# javascript in operator and events

Tags: javascript

update:

```
for( i in window)if(i=='onhashchange')console.log(i, window[i]); //prints onchangechange undefined
```

on browser where onhashchange event is supported I have

```
'onhashchange' in window;  //returns true
window['onhashchange']; //returns false
window.onhashchange;  //returns false;
```

why does the former returns true and the rest returns false?

Comment: onhashchange is non-standard (as far as I know), and therefore not fully supported. I expect it was either being phased out or some weird thing. Try a setInterval loop. Now, you are clearly an experienced JavaScript developer with the use of window['onhashchange'], but I have frankly never heard of it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with help of the first operation you just check if such an event is in window object, so it returns true. Two other tell you if such a handler is implemented, and there is no implementation yet you get false.
Can you check the following:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {}
window['onhashchange'];
```

yea, anyway it will return true now, because we have defined that variable... So most probably

```
'onhashchange' in window;
```

just checks if browser supports it

```
window['onhashchange']; //returns false
window.onhashchange;  //returns false;
```

just checks if handler already implemented

PS. Also you can be interesting in [Javascript IN operator compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920765/javascript-in-operator-compatibility), here @Andy E wrote:

> You should err on the side of caution when using it to check event support. All implementations except Mozilla support "eventname" in element as a test for DOM events, **Firefox will result in false here unless a handler is defined**.

**UPDATE:** to see difference between "x in window" and "window.x" (which is equal to window['x']), take a look at the following script and its output:

```
var foo = {};
console.info( 'bar' in foo ); // false, because no such proeprty
console.info( foo.bar ); // undefined, because no such property
console.info( foo.bar ? 'true' : 'false' ); // 'false' because no such property

foo = { bar: false };
console.info( 'bar' in foo ); // true, because there is such property
console.info( foo.bar ); // false, because this is value of bar property
console.info( foo.bar ? 'true' : 'false' ); // 'false' because foo.bar is false

foo = { bar: 1 }; 
console.info( 'bar' in foo ); // true, because there is such a property
console.info( foo.bar ); // 1, because this is value of bar proeprty
console.info( foo.bar ? 'true' : 'false' ); // 'true', because foo.bar is 1 (which is not 0 which meant to be false)

foo = { bar: 0 }; 
console.info( 'bar' in foo ); // true, because there is such a property
console.info( foo.bar ); // 0, because this is value of bar proeprty
console.info( foo.bar ? 'true' : 'false' ); // 'false', because foo.bar is 0 (which meant to be false)
```

**UPDATE2:** [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/)  - this article shows how to make event detection cross browser (because "event in window" does not work in Mozilla; this article also answers why it is so)

Comment: without going into browser issue but from pure javascript perspective, how is x in window different from the window[x], window.x?

Comment: the way that "x in window" checks if such a property exists, "window[x] / window.x" returns value of that property if such a property exists. I will answer update with example to show

Answer (score 2):

Could it be simply that the `window` object has a property called `onhashchange`, but the value of the property is currently `null` and therefore considered false?

```
var a = { 'foo': null }
console.log('foo' in a) // true
console.log(a.foo) // null
console.log(!!a.foo) // false
```

…where the `!!` is a double negation, a trick to convert value to true/false.