# Unusual if (a in b) JavaScript syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have just stumbled upon the following webpage and am somewhat intrigued by the use of the `in` keyword.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/examples/input-autofocus-with-fallback.html

- Is this valid JavaScript?
- Do all browsers accept this?
- How does it actually work?

They are using this syntax for fallback when web browser doesn't support the `autofocus` attribute. So this would lead me to believe that this syntax is valid.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920765/javascript-in-operator-compatibility

Comment: @Marc thanks for pointing that out, very detailed explanation. MDN is a good resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in) operator checks if a property is defined on an object. So, this is valid Javascript and is accepted in almost all browsers.
In this case, the code is checking if "autofocus" is a property of a new element. If it is, then most likely the browser supports `autofocus` and will not need `.focus()` (or someone may be extending prototypes).

Answer (score 4):

You can think of it like this:

```
"localStorage" in window; // true
!!window["localStorage"]; // true
window["localStorage"] !== undefined; // true
```

These statements are basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

"autofocus" is an arbitrary boolean attibute that the script looks for. It's really no different than `<input id="q" class="autofocus">`, except in this case, the script would need to look for the class name (which a lot of validation scripts usually use) versus the attribute.

The browser doesn't "support" it, the script makes it work.