# Checking if an associative array exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

I had the same question as posed here: [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript) .

However, I'm looking for a method which will work in all major browsers including IE 6+. The method I saw which I liked is the use of the `in` operator, which I've never seen before.

I tried something different in google chrome which seemed to work, but I'd like to know why its not used instead of the `in` operator.

For reference:

```
var data = {foo : "bar"};
console.log("foo" in data); // true
console.log("bar" in data); // false
```

My proposal:

```
var data = {foo : "bar"};
console.log(!!data.foo); // true
console.log(!!data.bar); // false
```

Are there any drawbacks with my (second) method?

Comment: Well obviously if the key value is falsy then you get a false negative

Comment: Try `var data = {foo: 0};` or `var data = {foo: false};` or `var data = {foo: ''};`. Of course if you know that your object will never contain such values, you are fine. But general solutions should work without any assumptions.

Comment: is this not more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IE6 does support `in`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920765/javascript-in-operator-compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an alternative because you didn't know about the `in` operator before, and assumed it was not supported by all major browsers. In fact, it *is* supported by all major browsers, including IE6. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k25hbz2%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

> Supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards.

I'll refrain from explaining the drawbacks of your proposed approach, since another answer and the comments already do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that the "in" operator can be very dubious. It will return true if the left hand side is a direct member or the righthand side, or part of the righthand side's prototype. I suggest using: .hasOwnProperty()

```
var obj = {foo: 0}
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')) //true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('bar')) //false
```

Answer (score 1):

The drawback to that is that, if your property value evaluates to a falsy, the lookup will fail as it is testing on value, not property existence. After all, `!!` coerces a value to its truthy/falsy value.

```
var obj = {foo: 0};
alert(!!obj.foo); //false
```

Solution:

```
alert(typeof obj.foo != 'undefined')
```

[EDIT - in response to a comment below about `hasOwnProperty()`, this is fine but the OP did not ask about own properties only, and `hasOwnProperty()`, as its name suggests, does not pick up inherited properties, so may not be suitable for the OP's requirement]

Comment: p.s. I should point out that the only caveat with my answer is it will not pick up properties whose value has been explicitly set to `undefined`. That said, I can't imagine why you'd set such properties...

Comment: solution is more verbose than `in` plus fails with the undefined value

Comment: See my first comment re: `undefined`. Yes, `in` is better but the OP wanted an alternative. Granted, `in` should suffice.

Comment: If you want a robust solution then you can always use `.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I thought of that, but the OP did not explicitly say he wanted to check for own properties, so with `hasOwnProperty` any inherited properties would not be picked up.

Comment: Where did he ask for alternatives to `in`? The main point of the question seems to be this part: "I tried something different in google chrome which seemed to work, but **I'd like to know why its not used instead of the `in` operator**."

Comment: Well OK, the exact question was "are there any drawbacks to this approach"? A point I have surely answered, no?